# Why can't I receive WhatsApp messages when the app is not in the foreground?

Tags: whatsapp-messenger, background-process

I have a Samsung j5. When I have WhatsApp Messenger open, it can receive messages, but if I leave the app, messages don't arrive any more. My mobile data is always on.

Comment: Are you closing the Application via the "Recent Apps" Menue? Or are you just "minimizing" it by hitting the home button?

Comment: @benjaminS Even by closing the WhatsApp tab in the recent apps, the app has a background listener called **MessageService**, which *should* notify when a message arrives. If the service is messing up, then it means that WhatsApp programmers are putting less attention in their job. And yes, I'm facing that issue too. <speculation>Better move out to Telegram, heh.</speculation>

Comment: Are you using hibernating apps like Greenify?

Comment: Is background data enable for WhatsApp?

Comment: I dnt use such apps

Comment: Where it show that background data is enable